# Whats the "rails dbconsole" equivalent for a react/node/sharetribe application?

Tags: node.js

In a rails application, the command "rails dbconsole" drops the developer in a mysql/psql prompt.

Is there an equivalent for a react node app ?
The specific app in question is
https://github.com/sharetribe/flex-template-web

Answer (score 0):

rails dbconsole is an interface to your database console. For example, if you use a postgres, your console will be a `psql`.

So, use psql directly if you haven't any interfaces to it.